# What is the request URL for ActiveCollab api cloud?

Tags: activecollab

Im trying to find the structure of the request url that i can send an http post/get requests to but can't seem to find it anywhere?

Can someone help please, I'm new with using AC?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveCollab Cloud accounts, if you would like to query a list of projects, you would GET a `/projects` resource, and it's available at:

```
https://app.activecollab.com/#ACCOUNT-ID#/api/v1/projects
```

`#ACCOUNT-ID#` is ID of your Cloud account.